# CFHTTP How to Ignore certificate name mismtach

Tags: mismatch, cfhttp

I am trying to consume a HTTPS based SOAP WebService via ColdFusion, but it is returning "Connection Failure".

On dumping the result variable, it showed:

**Error Detail:** "I/O Exception: Name in certificate 'subdomain1.domain.com' does not match host name 'subdomain2.domain.com'"

I can ignore such warning if I browse the HTTPS wsdl in browser, But the Question is; How can I bypass this warning using <CFHTTP>?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "consume".

Comment: calling a webservice using the CFHTTP tag.

<cfhttp url="https-url?wsdl" method="post" result="KReturn">

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to have the host of the service.  Get a proper SSL certificate for that subdomain or a wildcard certificate that will allow them to have as many subdomains as needed with a single certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution to this as well (a well-known payment gateway provider has an SSL issue on their server I have to work around).  One solution I came up with was to put an entry into the server's hosts file and set it to the IP address of the hostname the SSL certificate was using.  Fortunately their web server just accepts connections based on IP rather than hostname, so I was able to fool my server into thinking that I was connecting to the "proper" hostname published in the SSL cert and override the IP for that hostname in the public DNS.  A way to tell Java that the name mismatch is "okay" would be nice though.